# Calculating witnesses for upper and lower bound

Tags: big-o

I'm studying the running time of programs and have come across the Big O notation. One is asked to prove that `T(n)` is `O(f(n))` by proving that there exists integer `x` and constant `c > 0` such that for all integers `n >= x`, `T(n) <= cf(n)`.

The examples I've seen prove this by "picking" values for `x` and `c`.  I understand that you can plug values into the equation and see if they are correct, but is there a way to actually calculate `x` or `c`?  Or, at least, some rules of thumb on how to pick them so one isn't plugging in values endlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values come from an examination from the algorithm `T`.  For example, when you have a simple loop:

```
for (i=0; i < n; ++i) {
  sum += i;
}
```

then you perform the operations `i<n`, `++i` and `sum+=i` n times, and `i=0` once.  So `f(n)==n`, `c==4` (for the four operations, elevating the "once" to "n times" for correctness of values), `x==1` (for `n==0`, you still perform `i=0` and `i<n`, so the formula would not work).  This gives you an O(n) performance (linear in the number of inputs).

For the nested loops:

```
for (i=0; i < n; ++i) {
  for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
    sum += j;
  }
}
```

The calculations are similar, with `f(n)==n^2`, giving you O(n^2).

So there is no cut-n-dry way of telling the exact values of `c` and `x`, but most of the time the hard part is coming up with `f` -- and the "smallest" of that too (an O(n^2) algorithm is also an O(n^3) algorithm according to the definition you provided, but you want to characterize that algorithm with O(n^2) instead of O(n^3)).  The ordering of `f`s is based on their growth when `n` approaches infinity: `f(n)=n^3` grows slower than `f(n)=2^n`, even if for small `n`s the former is larger than the latter.

Note that in theory the actual values of `x` and `c` become irrelevant as `n` approaches infinity, that is why they don't show up in the `O(n)` notation itself.  This does not mean, however that for (relatively) small values if `n`, the number of instructions are not much larger than `f(n)` (e.g. you have 1000 instructions within the for loop).

Also, the O(n) notation gives you *worst* performance, which might be much higher than what you observe in real life (average-case cost) or in the overall usage of a data structure (amortized cost), for example.